# Missing data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, database-design

I have a SQL challenge

My data provider send me a CSV data formatted like the example below
Now for some reason the file is missing data perhaps to save space and make the tables smaller, I'm not sure.

In the Field_1 and Field_2 there is missing data. the data is present in one record and the following records have NULL values until the next record. so in the example below in the second and third records of the Field_1 the value should be "ID_1" and not NULL same goes for Field_2 the values should be ABC and not NULL

```
Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
-----------------------
ID_1    ABC    Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_3  --> ID_1   ABC   Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_3  --> ID_1   ABC   Value_3
ID_2    CDE    Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_4  --> ID_2   CDE   Value_4
ID_3    EFG    Value_X
```

So far I wrote an excel module that fixes my data before I import it however the files will start coming in really big and excel will not be able to handle this.
So my option would be to use TSQL cursor and perform some procedure that will fill in the data. or I could structure my select queries to compensate for the missing data and generate virtual table with filled in data before running select on the data

What would be the best solution for this? My requirements would be happy medium between low maintenance and space efficiency
I'm talking about 17 fields with missing data and about 150,000 records a month.

Thanks for help

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: If you don't know why it is missing data then how are you sure the value should be the last value in that column?   I know this is not tagged .NET but a front end parser is the way I would handle this.  If not you need to put an identity on the table so you can reproduce the row order and then it is just a join to the prior row.

Comment: I agree with the identity on the table as the data makes only sense if the order of the records is preserved. So are you saying that I should fill in the missing records before importing the data ?

Comment: I am saying if you don't fix it prior to import then you must have an identity or you will not know the order.  A table has no set order.  You must order by column so get an order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you cannot ask your data provider for another format?
Because it seems the file is not well formatted.

Comment: Not well formatted could be intentional, the format is consistent and there is some logic behind it so this is what I have to work with.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two cardinal rules for loading data into databases:

1. Don't munge the data.  As the data are delivered, so shall they be loaded.
2. It's OK to *add* data at load time, and it's OK to change representations.  For example, you can add line numbers or a filename, as new columns, and you can change useless `"N/A"` or `"NULL"` strings to zero-length strings, creating NULLs in the database.  Standard Unix tools are great for that purpose; many are [available on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net).

Another good policy is:

3. Don't use a cursor.  If you're tempted to use a cursor, you're thinking about rows.  Think about sets instead.

In your case, as others pointed out, your idea of how to supply proxy value for missing ones -- by using "earlier" values -- depends on knowing the order the rows appeared in in the CSV file.  In database theory, that's known as *implicit meaning* in the data.  In SQL, we have only *explicit meaning*: for one row to be "before" another, there must be a column to compare.

So: number the lines, and load the NULLs, so to speak.

You then have the information you need to get the effect you want: you can join the table to itself, and coalesce the relevant "earlier" data with the missing data.  There's no need for triggers or anything exotic.  Just find the last "good" row, and use those values in place of missing ones.

```
create table T (line, Field_1, Field_2, Field_3);
insert into T values
  (1, 'ID_1', 'ABC', 'Value_3')
, (2, NULL, NULL, 'Value_3')
, (3, NULL, NULL, 'Value_3')
, (4, 'ID_2', 'CDE', 'Value_3')
, (5, NULL, NULL, 'Value_4')
, (6, 'ID_3', 'EFG', 'Value_X');

create view vT as
select   a.line
       , coalesce(a.Field_1, b.Field_1) as Field_1
       , coalesce(a.Field_2, b.Field_2) as Field_2
       , a.Field_3
from T as a join T as b
on b.line = ( -- last line before a.line with good values (unless a is good)
    select max(line) from T
    where line <= a.line
    and Field_1 is not NULL
    and Field_2 is not NULL
);

select * from T;
select * from vT;
```

Output:

```
line        Field_1     Field_2     Field_3   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           ID_1        ABC         Value_3   
2                                   Value_3   
3                                   Value_3   
4           ID_2        CDE         Value_3   
5                                   Value_4   
6           ID_3        EFG         Value_X   

line        Field_1     Field_2     Field_3   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           ID_1        ABC         Value_3   
2           ID_1        ABC         Value_3   
3           ID_1        ABC         Value_3   
4           ID_2        CDE         Value_3   
5           ID_2        CDE         Value_4   
6           ID_3        EFG         Value_X
```

The `coalesce` function takes a column list and returns the first non-NULL value.  The `b` row is guaranteed not to have NULLs; the `a` row might not.  If `a` is good, we use that, else we take from `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand...

You said:

> so in the example below in the second and third records of the Field_1 the value should be "ID_1" and not NULL same goes for Field_2 the values should be ABC and not NULL

```
Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
-----------------------
ID_1    ABC    Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_3
ID_2    CDE    Value_3
NULL    NULL   Value_4
ID_3    EFG    Value_X
```

If I take what you said and apply it to the table, it would look like this...

```
Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
-----------------------
ID_1    ABC    Value_3
ID_1    ABC    Value_3
ID_1    ABC    Value_3
ID_2    CDE    Value_3
ID_2    CDE    Value_4
ID_3    EFG    Value_X
```

So, assuming you want the replica data, you could just import it into the table, and make a stored procedure that copies the data from the line which is fully populated, and inserts it into the rows that have the same Field_1 ID?

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. so either I process the data and fill in the non populated fields or just write a query in a way that it will compensate for this. I'm not sure which more efficient

Comment: Using a query would probably be preferable to doing it yourself as it wouldn't use up your personal time.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it. However, please find out the real order of your table and replace `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as row_num
    FROM   YourTable
)
SELECT  
     Field_1 = ISNULL(Field_1,(SELECT TOP 1 Field_1 FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.Field_1 IS NOT NULL AND c1.row_num < c.row_num ORDER BY c1.row_num DESC)) 
    ,Field_2 = ISNULL(Field_2,(SELECT TOP 1 Field_2 FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.Field_2 IS NOT NULL AND c1.row_num < c.row_num ORDER BY c1.row_num DESC))  
    ,Field_3
FROM    cte c
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was doing with excel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A table has no inherent order.
Even a table with a clustered PK is not ordered.
In the absence of an order by clause there is no guaranteed order to a select

For that reason if you are going to fix the data in SQL you need to insert with an identity so you can reproduce the order.

I would update the data so you only have to do it once
A select to find the data above it is a fairly expensive query

This just does one row at at time and one column but it is a start

```
update tableTarget
   set tableTarget.Field_1 = tableSource.Field_1 
  from table as tableTarget 
  join table as tableSource 
    on tableTarget.Iden = tableSource.Iden + 1 
   and tableTarget.Field_1 is null 
   and tableSource.Field_1 is not null
```

Now this only does one pair at a time so if you up to 4 nulls in a row then you will need to run it 4 times
Run it until is says zero rows updated
But you could have 4 nulls in a row hundreds of times and still only need to run it 4 times

I know running the same update multiple times seems like a hassle but it is a very efficient update
Based on the sample data there is only a few nulls in a row

This is not tested
It is not as efficient but you only need to run it once for each column

```
update tableTarget
   set tableTarget.Field_1 = (select top 1 tableSource.Field_1 
                                from table as tableSource
                               where tableSource.Field_1 is not null 
                                 and tableSource.Iden < tableTarget.iden 
                               order by tableSource.Iden desc )
  from table as tableSource 
 where tableTarget.Field_1 is null
```

Comment: As is an alias - this is using one table

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these queries and they all work. that being said they take forever to complete
I able to do this with excel 10 times faster

I'm curious if it wouldn't be faster to accomplish this using the CURSOR